# How to convert epoch timestamp of format TimeStamp = \/Date(1388514600000+0530)\/ to TimeStamp = \/Date(1400321676266)\/

Tags: java, date, datetime

I am calling a .net REST service from java, in my json response sometimes I am getting timestamp in the format

```
TimeStamp1 = \/Date(138851460000+0530)\/
```

and sometimes in the format

```
TimeStamp2 = \/Date(1400321676266)\/
```

1. Is there a java API to convert `TimeStamp1` format to `TimeStamp2` format?
2. Right now, I am taking out the time in ms from `Timestamp1` & `Timestamp2` using basic string operation, I am not sure if `Date(138851460000+0530)` is a standard format of date, (couldn't find anything related to this in java). Otherwise I guess I will have to live with `String` operation.

Comment: The first includes a timezone specification.  The second is presumably GMT.  (Is the first missing a digit?)

Comment: Yes you are right , first includes the timezone specification specification which Is IST i guess, second is GMT. But I don't know at run time what is coming, so looking for a generic solution say if tomorrow some other timezone comes up.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the various date facilities in Java (the original stuff never made sense and they over-complicated it after that, and I've not had a need to learn).  You may have to pre-process the second to add "+0000" before running it through a date parser, or whatever.  Though it's not clear that there's a standard ISO formatter pattern for this.

Comment: Note that the (sorta) correct way to convert the first to the second would be to multiply out the offset value represented by the timezone and add/subtract that to the milliseconds.